# How to change background-color on button click

Tags: css, angular

I want to change the background-color of the button when it's clicked.

app.component.html:

```
    <button #LABEL *ngFor="let filtre of act" id="{{filtre.id}}" class="{{filtre.id}}"
        [attr.data-label]="filtre.label"
        (click)="applyFilterActivite(LABEL)"
        value="{{filtre.label}}">
            {{filtre.label}}
    </button>
```

p.component.ts:

```js
    this.act = [
      {
        id: 'p',
        label: 'P'
      },
      {
        id: 've',
        label: 'VE'
      },
      {
        id: 'o',
        label: 'O'
      },
    
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "when it's clicked" you mean, while it's being pressed, you can use the CSS selector `:active`.

Assuming the style will be the same for all, first give a class that is common to each of the buttons you generate:

```
     <button #LABEL *ngFor="let filtre of act" id="{{filtre.id}}" class="myButton {{filtre.id}}"
            [attr.data-label]="filtre.label"
            (click)="applyFilterActivite(LABEL)"
            value="{{filtre.label}}">
      {{filtre.label}}
    </button>
```

Then style it:

```css
.myButton:active {
    background-color: purple;
}
```

If instead you meant "give it a different style *once it's clicked*", then you can make the click event assign a class to the button:

```
(click)="applyFilterActivite(LABEL); $event.target.classList.add('myClickedButton')"
```

And style it:

```css
.myClickedButton {
    background-color: purple;
}
```

Comment: thank you for you'r answer , but i don't understand why my IDE don't accept this.classList.add('myClickedButton') i have this error  : Property 'classList' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

Comment: My bad. `this` doesn't work that way there. You can use a function similar to your `applyFilterActivite()` and pass in a reference to the element (such as `LABEL`), then access the html element and then `classList`. I will edit my post later with a more complete answer.

Comment: @bad I edited the answer. Notice how it takes the `$event` data's `target` to refer to the html element itself. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem.